# HTTPS protocal is not working using laravel 5.6 with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, https

I am using laravel 5.6 with nginx for web api purpose. But when i call https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user
It shows "Secure Connection Failed" error message in the browser.

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8000. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.

Learn more…

Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites
```

I have used middleware and forcessl. But no luck.

Comment: Does it work with the localhost:8000 ?

Comment: The error says 800, you say 8000. Which is it?

Comment: It should be 8000, as per the https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

Comment: Its just while partialy copying typo mistake. Now i edited to 8000. This issue happended production only. Here I just changed the IP.

Comment: Any idea or solution  ?